# Animation not working on component in ReactJS.

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend

Good day. I have been attempting to create the animation demonstrated [here](https://codepen.io/vineethtr/pen/LAEyw) in ReactJS. I have using that codepen as a loose reference, yet the animation doesn't work when I press the login button on my own project implementing this effect on the [login page](https://github.com/TheMasteredPanda/reactjs-dynamic-login).

What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Duke J. Morgan.

The specific aspects of my project that, as far am I aware, are primary components in the login page that, in this problem, might be the cause of the problem I mentioned above:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class LoginComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        incorrect: false
    }

}

onLoginButtonClick() {
    let passwordInput = document.getElementById("passwordInput");

    if (passwordInput.innerHTML !== "test") {
        // passwordInput.classList.add("incorrect-login");
        let copy = this.state;
        copy.incorrect = true;
        console.log(`Incorrect boolean: ${copy.incorrect}`);
        this.setState(copy);
        return;
    }

    this.props.setPage();
}

render() { 
    return (<div className="box" id="loginBox">
        <h2 className="title">Username</h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" className="input"/>
        <h2 className="title">Password</h2>
        <input id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password" className={`input ${this.state.incorrect ? 'incorrect-login' : ''}`} type="password"/>
        {/* <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a> */}
        <button className="button" id="login" onClick={() => {this.onLoginButtonClick()}}>Login</button>
    </div>);
}
}
export default LoginComponent;


//The CSS of the login box. incorrect-login is the class added to the password input element when the login button is clicked but the incorrect password, or no password, has been entered. 
#loginBox {
.title:nth-child(1) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.title:nth-child(3) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.incorrect-login {
    margin: 4px auto;
    width: 70%;
    height: 15%;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    animation: move 10s;
}
}

@keyframes move {
0%, 100% { left: 0px;}
20% , 60%{left: 15px;}
40% , 80%{left: -15px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the css. I think you should make separated classes for the login and incorrect-login.

```
.login {
    margin: 4px auto;
    width: 70%;
    height: 15%;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

.incorrect-login {
    border: 2px solid red;
    animation: move 10s;
}
```

If you want to use property "left" in animation you have also add property position: absolute; to the component's class.

And code for the password input class name should be:

```
className={`input ${this.state.incorrect ? 'login incorrect-login' : 'login'}`}
```

Also you should not use document.getElementById in React applications directly. If you really need to get reference of the dom element created by React, you should use [ref prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) instead.